# Entity Framework with extra data in navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code First.

Given these two classes,

```
public class Parts
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}

public class SubParts
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

I've to define a navigation property to get this (ie):

- Part1

  - SubPart1 - Order 1
  - SubPart5 - Order 2
  - SubPart2 - Order 3
- Part2

  - SubPart5 - Order 1
  - SubPart3 - Order 2
  - SubPart6 - Order 3
  - SubPart2 - Order 4

... and so on.

My question is: How must I manage the property named Order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am understanding right. Your table SubParts doesn't have the column Order but you want to include Order Property here.

Comment: Your understanding is true. But I'dont want to include the Order Property there. Instead i'm asking where must it be.

Comment: I don't see any solution but if you want add Order property here you can add [NotMapped] attribute with the property inside SubParts table which will not affect our table.

Comment: How did you map the relationship between Part and SubPart?

Comment: Surely with a public virtual ICollection<SubParts> SubParts {get; set;} statement.

Comment: remove virutal to not included the **SubParts** automatically (lazy loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://adrianscorner.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/designing-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-additional-fields-using-entity-framework/).

In my example, the classes I've define to implement this model are:

```
public class Parts
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PartsSubParts> SubParts {get; set; }
}

public class SubParts
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}

public class PartsSubParts
{
    public virtual Parts Part {get; set; }
    public virtual SubParts SubPart {get; set;}

    public int Order {get; set; }
}
```